# Importing data from Excel file into SQL Server 2012 database using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, excel, file-upload, sql-server-2012

I have a `users` table with columns like `Name, Family, email, ranking`, ... and an Excel file that has users data.

How can I import the data from the Excel file into the table using asp.net and C#?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please read [ask] from SO, then reformat your question to meet the criteria.

Comment: Suppose, you will need this http://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/ to parse Excel files

Comment: Ignore the SSIS portion and just use .NET [Excel source through script](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2013/04/ssis-excel-source-via-script.html)